# Does paste of Licorice root, Burdock root and Dandelion root reverses Hairfall?

Tags: dermatology, hair, hairloss, scalp

I am suffering from hair fall from last five year. Whenever i comb my hair hard, small pieces of deal cell start falling from scalp. I tried PRP(Plasma riched platelates) and Minoxidill 5% but that dosen't worked much.

I read on some blogs on internet that a paste of Licorice root, Burdock root and Dandelion root reverses hair fall. As these things are little expensive so before using i want to take suggestion of anyone who have tried it or anyone who have knowledge about it.

Are these herbs really effective for hairloss problem?

Answer (score -1):

Licorice root which is also called Mulethi in Hindi is excellent for reducing hair fall. One of the main reasons of hair fall is inadequate diet and infections on the scalp skin. Licorice as an anti-bacterial agent which cures the infections on scalp like eczema. Dandelion root is also known for reducing hair fall.

I have personally not used Licorice or Dandelion but I have used Bringraj Juice and a few other [medicines](https://honeyfurforher.com/natural-hair-treatment-for-reversing-premature-grey-hair-alopecia-hair-loss/), and a self-prepared ayurvedic shampoo to reduce hair fall. If you are interested below is the recipe that I use which has miraculously reduced my hairfall to a great extent

Purchase shikakai, reetha and amla powders and mix them in equal quantities (100gm). Add 50gm of Methi seeds powder to the mixture. Store it in a container. It wont go bad. Now take a tablespoon of this mixture and add a very small amount of water in it to make a thick paste. Leave it for at least 3 - 4 hours before bath. Use this as a hair mask and wash it off after 10 minutes. Avoid getting this in your eyes while bathing because shikakai powder can really irritate the eyes.

Comment: Welcome to Health.SE, Swati Rawat. Since health is an important topic, the site has a strict policy that all answers should be [backed up with reliable references](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/should-we-require-references-to-back-up-all-answers) so that the answer can be independently verified. *See [this list of reliable sources](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/783/quality-of-references/784#784)*. We now have only your word and a random net page. If you still have trouble with this, feel free to visit the [help] or [meta].